# Synchronous Postgres Replication to Clickhouse

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, clickhouse

I have a problem replicating postgres to clickhouse. I can easily create materialized postgresql engine and it works fine. But we need to have synchronous commits work so that any write to our main postgres db should wait for the same writes to be written to clickhouse before the transaction is completed.

I tried adding the following setting to postgresql config. But this prevents clickhouse from replicating.

```
synchronous_commit:  "on"
synchronous_standby_names:  "'*'"
```

Comment: You are probably mixing up streaming replication and whatever tool you use to replicate to clickhouse. But even if you get that to work, it probably won't make you happy, because single-line `INSERT`s is a workload where column store databases like clickhouse perform badly. Think of something smarter, less synchronous.

Comment: better uze debezium + kafka + altinity kafka sink
https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-sink-connector